# I installed smbldap-tools but can't find /usr/share/doc/smbldap-tools/examples

Tags: 14.04, samba, ldap, openldap

When I try to reinstall the `smbldap-tools` package the error says that it's impossible to find the source package.

Comment: Can you please provide the commands used and the output of them.

Comment: `cd /usr/share/doc/smbldap-tools/examples/` and the output was 
no such file or folder so i tried to reinstall `apt-get install smbldap-tools` the output is dpkg-source not found

Comment: Please [edit] and provide the full output of `LANG=C sudo apt-get install smbldap-tools` using the [formatting tools](https://$SITEURL$/help/formatting).

Comment: dpkg-sources is available over `sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev`, but it's strange that package request this command.